# How to append jquery cloned row to a hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a Cloned table in my form. I Want Cloned Field Id's in Rails Params(parameter Hash) along with Form_for fields to save in DB. so i need to know how that cloned TR ids will append to hidden field in array so it will be added in params.
here is my code which i am  using to clone.`lastRow.closest('.content_value').clone().removeClass('content_value').addClass('clone_content_value').insertAfter(".clone_content_head:last");` 
or if there is any other way to get cloned tr values in Rails params then please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

try below code to append data to hidden field:

```
var data = lastRow.closest('.content_value').clone().removeClass('content_value').addClass('clone_content_value')
$(".hidden_field_class").append(data)
```

Comment: if i do by this way then Cloned TR will not be visible.. i need cloned TR at two Places one at the last of original Tr and another In hidden Field

Comment: make it visible by css property ie $(".field_name").css("display", "block")

Answer (score 0):

I solved It by this code..

```
var arr = []
$lastRow.closest('.content_value').find("td:last").each(function(){
 arr.push($(this).html())
$("input.hiddenFieldClass").val(arr)  
});
```